# seeing a gap below images in WKWebView?

Tags: css, uiwebview

Just trying to help others and spread the word:

Are you seeing a gap at the bottom of images in WKWebView so that some of the top portion of your image is being cut off? Several of our properties' apps were witnessing this after moving from UIWebView to WKWebView and we were able to find a fix.

**solution: apply `display:block` to your `<img>` elements**

Here's a screenshot of what we were seeing with a 320x50 ad cut off because of a gap/margin below the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9VmB.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Answer (score 0):

solution: apply `display:block` to your `<img>` elements